# $0 \leq x-y \leq a_n<\epsilon$ implying $x=y$?

Tags: real-analysis

> If for a real sequence $\{a_n\}$ and real $x,y$, we have $$0 \leq x-y \leq a_n<\epsilon$$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for all arbitrarily small $\epsilon >0$, can we say $x=y$?

---

This came to my mind while solving a real analysis problem, however I'm not sure if the above statement is true or not. What I think it says is that $x,y$ can get as close as we want them to, their distance get squeezed by $\epsilon$ but I'm not sure, if I can say that $x=y$?

Comment: The order in which $n$ and $\epsilon$ are mentioned is important, as it is over which set they range. As written, this is only possible for $a_n=x-y=0$. So, yes, we get $x=y$. More interesting is the statement "For all arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$ and all *sufficiently large* $n$ $0\leq x-y\leq a_n<\epsilon$". This also implies $x=y$ by assuming $x-y>0$ and taking $0<\epsilon<x-y$.

Comment: @NDB What if for all $n$, $a_n>0$?

Comment: The way you wrote it, that could not happen, because the statement would not be true for $n=1$ and $\epsilon=a_1/2$, since $0\leq x-y\leq a_1<a_1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Just denote $\delta:=x-y$. If $\delta>0$, then you would find some $0<\epsilon<\delta$. You then get that

$$ \delta=x-y< \epsilon <\delta. $$

That can never be the case.

Comment: Why would $\epsilon$ be between $x-y$ and $0$? It's already given that $\epsilon>x-y$

Comment: @Ellie_Wong You assume $\delta>0$. Then there exists a positive small enough $\epsilon$ smaller than $\delta$. This epsilon will satisfy your given inequality, so $x-y<\epsilon$. Your quantifiers say that for some $x,y$ and every $0<\epsilon$, the inequality holds. You can always choose an $\epsilon$ as I said.

Comment: Oh i completely forgot you can vary epsilon ! Thanks a lot!